# get list of all users connected using wifi tethering in android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, tethering

I am trying to get list of all connected users in wifi tethering. I know that i have to read `dnsmasq.leases` but the question is, where can I get this file from my mobile?

If i look at source code of wifi tethering open source app

i get the file path in here

```
this.coretask.setPath(this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getParent());
this.DATA_FILE_PATH+"/var/dnsmasq.leases"
```

I might not be using this app for wifi tethering. So then how can i get the file location to read all connected users?

Comment: Why are you creating dependency on some external app data.. keep your own list

Comment: @userSeven7s and how can i achieve that? the app who creates his own tethering table will have all the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not create a dependency of your app on some external app data.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233068/android-application-wifi-device-ap-connectivity)  to know how to get the list of connected WiFi devices.

You can use Zero-conf bonjour protocol to discover other devices.

[Android application Wi-Fi device - AP connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233068/android-application-wifi-device-ap-connectivity)

Comment: the simple answer is, your app should create your own routing table instead of getting info from other wifi apps, your own app should connect with other devices then do else procedure

Comment: Use bonjour for discovering other devices.

Comment: What if the devices aren't advertising services using bonjour?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a new file, and catch usernames as they enter the wifi, writing to the file. Then remove names when they leave the wifi, instead of constantly checking names. Maybe check once every 10 seconds? +1 if this helps, -1 if it doesn't.

Sorry for lack of formatting, but I'm on my phone.

Comment: NO that is not what i want. I want to list all already connected tehthered users. In 2.3.3 mobiles, there is builtin tethering option avaliable too