# How to find the total number of devices connected and details in Android Wifi tethering mode?

Tags: android, android-wifi, tethering

I have successfully created the wifi tethering in android device. I would like to get the details of the devices connected in  the wifi tethered device through coding.

I have gone through the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319503/4073227. Here i am able to get details of the connected devices. But it returns also the device which was previously connected. How to find the currently connected device information?

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you device is rooted, you can get the details through dnsmasq.leases file. Which is usually placed in - /data/misc/dhcp/dnsmasq.leases.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hi. Thanks for the answer. My device is not rooted.